# <video> tags disappear on pages (but not on posts!)

Tags: videos, troubleshooting

I'm creating my first theme.

If I add the following content to a post, the video displays fine on the site:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="http://domain.com/videos/whatever.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
Install <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox" target="_blank">
<strong>Firefox</strong></a> or <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome" target="_blank">
<strong>Chrome</strong></a> to watch the video.</video></p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://localhost/2012/02videos/">go back</a></p>
```

However, if I add **the same content** to a page, this is what I get when viewing the source:

```
 <p>Instal Firefox or Chrome to watch the video. go back <a href="http://localhost/page/">Read more</a></p>
```

It doesn't matter if it's a new post / page or if I change content of an existing one. I'm running WP 3.6 pt-br, I have disabled all the plugins and the issue persists. If I use other themes (twenty thirteen, twenty ten, etc) everything works fine. My functions.php file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the current theme, there was no `page.php` file present, so WordPress was reading `index.php` and, according to the theme's instructions, displaying `the_excerpt()`. It will strip many tags, including `<video>`, and that's *exactly* what was happening.

The content of the posts is is displayed based (mainly) on the contents of the file `single.php`, but for pages it is (mainly) the file `page.pgp`. (For more detailed information, everything is well explained and documented in [the Template Hierarchy section on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)).

[image]